# Should salutations be removed from questions?

Tags: discussion

While reviewing suggested edits I noticed that some users sometimes edit others posts and remove salutations like

> [Question text which follows the rules]
>
> ...
>
> Thanks!

or

> [Question text which follows the rules]
>
> ...
>
> Thanks a lot
>
> [Name]

Should we remove salutations? I personally wouldn't like it if somebody else edits my posts like that. At least thanking in advance should be ok in my opinion. Begin polite is also part of a community. I'd suggest to only remove extended salutations, e.g. if they more look like these much-beloved 10 line mail signatures.

What is your take on this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The rules for stackoverflow apply to magento.SE.
[See this for reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/224252).
I read some of the answers (I hope I didn't miss something importan) and my conclusion is salutations are kind of a grey area. They are not encouraged but they are not banned.

Signing your posts...a big NO NO. You shouldn't do that.

Comment: *"Signing your posts...a big NO NO. You shouldn't do that."* - I completely agree! - Ben Marks, Developer & Community Evangelist, Magento, an eBay Inc Company, MCAB, MCD, MCD+, MCFD, MCSS, Sagittarius, Isle of Palms, SC...

Comment: @benmarks. Sorry the name doesn't ring a bell. Can you give me more info, please?

Answer (score 5):

When editing questions, I always remove "fluff" like that, as it is policy on StackOverflow as well, but I wouldn't go so far to edit questions *just* to remove "Thank you".

What I consider fluff:

- "thanks"
- salutation and signing
- irrelevant information about the poster (like "I am new to Magento")
- irrelevant information about the problem (like "this is urgent!!!111")

Side note: When reading "Thanks in advance", I always think about [the quote](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html):

> this connotes an intention not to thank anybody afterwards

Answer (score 3):

"Welcome to Magento.SE!" is a standard I use for first-timers. I think this should be an exception and be allowed.

Comment: yup. Me too using this. It should be allowed

Answer (score 0):

Say Hi at first and an anticipated Thanks at the end just make it polite and no disturbance for the following readers.

Signing : Agreed with Marius answer, a big no no, simply because no matter what, the post is signed already, so that becomes redundant...