# Should remove "Thanks" in the question or not?

Tags: discussion, editing, questions

When editing a question, I try to keep "Thanks" in the content. Others try to remove it? What should we do in this case?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/224252

Comment: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/503/should-salutations-be-removed-from-questions/505#505

Answer (score 10):

In my opinion a sentence like "thank you" does not add anything to the question, as also introductions (like "I'm a newbie" additions) do not add valuable information.

I tend to remove "Thank you" from anywhere, but I do edit a lot, and I have [*Edit Questions And Answers* privileges](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) (>2000 rep), so then you don't need approvals from reviewers.

I think it would be good to remove superfluous additions as "thank you" if you are already changing/improving other things in a question. I think it is better not to suggest these superfluous edits if you do not have reached the *Edit Questions And Answers* privilege as I think the reviewers that have to review such edits can use their time in a better way.

Answer (score 7):

You have mentioned two different scenario

1. Keep Thanks as a editor
2. Reviewer of edit

In first scenario you keep "Thank you" It's ok For me as well site (I think)

In the second scenario if editor has made some more good edit then accept those edits.

And if editor removes only thank you from question or post, then reject those edit mark as no improvement

This is what I do. Otherwise all people have their own believe and own thinking about this.

Answer (score 7):

I leave "Thanks" lines in questions, but I've no problem if it is removed along with other edit (fixed tags or other stuff), **but** it makes no sense to edit questions just to remove this.

Actually "Teja Bhagavan Kollepara" makes a lot of such and it brings up old questions w/o any further improvements :(

**Can a moderator please *ask* him to stop this?**

---

From [Should salutations be removed from questions?](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/503/should-salutations-be-removed-from-questions/505#505)

> When editing questions, I always remove "fluff" like that, as it is policy on StackOverflow as well, **but I wouldn't go so far to edit questions just to remove "Thank you".**

---

**Edit:**

... and you probabbly should not **[add](https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/92557)** thank you lines. :)